# Joining two mysql tables to get a true/false column

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working with PHP and MySql. I'm trying to find a way to select a number of movies from a mysql table, but apart from the movies table I have a watchlist table that stores a userID and the movieID of the movies he/she has added to his/her watchlist:

```
id        userID      movieID
=====================================
1          1            3
2          1            5
3          1            7
4          2            3
5          2            2
6          3            2
```

The movies table looks something like this

```
movieID    title    duration
=============================
1          tit1       34:43  
2          tit2       35:43   
3          tit3       24:43     
4          tit4       34:13   
5          tit5       11:43    
6          tit6       22:43    
7          tit7       33:43
```

The result I'm after is (for example for the user with ID 1):

```
movieID    title    duration   added
=======================================
1          tit1       34:43     false
2          tit2       35:43     false
3          tit3       24:43     true
4          tit4       34:13     false
5          tit5       11:43     true
6          tit6       22:43     false
7          tit7       33:43     true
```

Is there a way to join both the movies and the watchlist table to produce the desired result?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/how-to-do-a-full-outer-join-in-mysql .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the required output by using a `LEFT JOIN` and then checking for a `NULL` in the join table.

```
SELECT m.*, IF(w.id IS NULL, 0, 1) AS added
FROM movies m 
LEFT JOIN watchlist w ON (m.movieID = w.movieID AND w.userID = 1)
GROUP BY m.movieID
```

Comment: This only selects the movies that have been added by user 1. I need to get all movies, showing false for those that the user has not added.

Comment: Oops. I've moved the `userID` condition onto the `JOIN`. Try that.